# How do I prove this reducibility result about biquadratic extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are quartic minimal polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ always reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87153/are-quartic-minimal-polynomials-over-mathbbq-always-reducible-over-mathbb)

This question was originally a homework problem for an algebra course, but the professor took it off the homework once he realized it was too hard. However, I am curious. Here is the question:

If $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ is a biquadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the minimal polynomial $f(x)$ of $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, prove that $f(x)$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but that $f(x)$ mod $p$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime number $p$.

Give an explicit example of such a polynomial $f(x)$

If anyone could even give me an example, that would be wonderful.

Comment: I think you want to read [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87153/are-quartic-minimal-polynomials-over-mathbbq-always-reducible-over-mathbb).

Comment: Thank you Dylan. I hope my question is not too redundant.

Comment: It's redundant, but that's fine! The two will probably be merged at some point.