# Example request: unramified field extension with a relative power integral basis?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

A field extension $L/K$ (of number fields) admits a *relative power integral basis* if $\mathcal{O}_L = \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$.  I'm looking for a simple example in which this occurs and $L/K$ is unramified.

I've found references that imply that this is possible, e.g. in [`A Note on Integral Bases of Unramified Cyclic Extensions of Prime Degree' (H. Ichimura)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02940919), but the difficulty in that series of papers is to construct extensions with power integral basis that do not have *normal integral bases*.  As such, I'd like to think that simpler examples exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** The former example has to be modified because it gave the trivial extension.

Let $K$ be such that the equation $a^2-4b=-1$ (**changed 1 to -1**) has a solution with $a,b\in O_K$.  Then $O_K[X]/(X^2+aX+b)$ is unramified over $O_K$ because it has invertible discriminant. So if $L=K[\alpha]$ with $\alpha$ a zero of $X^2+aX+b$, then 
$O_L=O_K[\alpha]$ (the right hand side is unramified over $O_K$, hence integrally closed) and $L/K$ is unramified.

As a concrete example, take $K=\mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$, $\alpha$ a zero of $X^2+\sqrt{3}X+1\in K[X]$ and $L=K[\alpha]$.

**Add** One can also say that the discriminant of the familly $\{1, \alpha\}$ is $-1$, so the discriminant of $O_L/O_K$ is $-1$. Which implies that $L/K$ is unramified.

To get a familly of examples, one can take for $b$ any positive integer.

For any $d\ge 3$, using a geometric interpretation on the polynomials $X^d+a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\dots+a_0$, with indeterminates $a_i$, one can show that there exists $L/K$ unramified of degree $d$ such that $O_L$ is monogeneous over $O_K$ (i.e. $O_L=O_K[\alpha]$).

Comment: Though I suppose the trivial field extension does actually satisfy all of the desired criteria...  :)

Comment: @CamMcLeman: sure :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example of a quadratic extension:

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ and let $L=K(i)$, where $i^2=-1$. As it turns out, $L$ is the Hilbert Class Field of $K$, and therefore $L/K$ is everywhere unramified.

Exercise 2.42 ([pages 51 and 52](http://books.google.com/books?id=DKrf26ogA0UC&pg=PA51)), in five parts, determines the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{m},\sqrt{n}]$ for $m$ and $n$ distinct squarefree integers different from $1$. (See [this question and response](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/81999/14699).) In particular, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-5})$ and therefore $\mathbb{O}_L$ has an integral basis $$B=\left\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\sqrt{-5},\frac{\sqrt{-5}+i}{2}\right\}.$$
Let $\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{-5}+i}{2}$. Then I claim that $\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha] = \mathcal{O}_L$. Clearly, $\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]\subseteq \mathcal{O}_L$, so it suffices to show that $B\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$.

We know that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Thus, $1,\sqrt{-5}$, and $\alpha$ belong to $\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$. Also, $i=2\alpha-\sqrt{-5}\in \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$. It remains to show that $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\in \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$, but
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = 1+i\cdot\frac{i+\sqrt{-5}}{2}=1+i\cdot \alpha\in \mathcal{O}_K[\alpha].$$
Hence, $\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]=\mathcal{O}_L$.