# find an integral basis for a composite of quadratic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $K:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[]a,\sqrt[]b)$ where $a,b$ coprime squarefree $\ne 1$ integers

Find an integral basis for the case $a ≡ 1\bmod 4$, $b ≡\ 2, 3\bmod 4$.

My attempt:

Denote $A:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[]a)$, $B:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[]b)$

We know that $\mathcal O_A=\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt[]a}{2}]$ and $\mathcal O_B=\Bbb Z[\sqrt[]b]$.

We know also that $\operatorname{disc}(\mathcal O_A)=a$ and $\operatorname{disc}(\mathcal O_B)=4b$,

so $\gcd(\operatorname{disc}(\mathcal O_A),\operatorname{disc}(\mathcal O_B))=1$ and $\mathcal O_{AB}=\mathcal O_K=\mathcal O_A \mathcal O_B$

Therefore since $\mathcal O_K$ is a ring, the family of integral elements $\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt[]a}{2},\sqrt[]b,\frac{1+\sqrt[]a}{2}\sqrt[]b\}$ generates $\mathcal O_K$ and is composed of integral elements since the product of integral elements is integral.

I showed that this family is linearly independent since $\{1,\sqrt[]a,\sqrt[]b,\sqrt[]{ab}\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[]a,\sqrt[]b]$, so its elements are linearly independent.

Is that correct? is there a more elegant way to find a basis?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See Arturo's answer in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/integers-in-biquadratic-extensions).