# Finding determinant of higher degree number fields.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I know I am forgetting something but I am not sure what. Could somebody please point me out in the real direction? I just want an explanation of the concept because I feel like I am confusing myself with all this and I am tired of getting myself confused with different incomplete explanation from various materials(I say incomplete because most just assume you have the maturity to catch their missing steps and as a non math student I find that very challenging.)

Given $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-1})$, how does one find its discriminant?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_class_field#Examples) they say, let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-15})$ of discriminant 
$-15$ so the field $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5})$ has discriminant $-15^2 = 225$ and so is an **everywhere unramified extension of K, and it is abelian**.

**Q1**. What concept are they using to say the discriminant of $L$ is $225$ as stated? I mean why is it square of $-15$? Do $L'=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{-5}), L'' = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{15}), L''' = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-15},\sqrt{1})$ also have the discriminant $-15^2 = 225$?

**Q2**. What does it mean by the bold part and how is it said so?

**Q3**. Am I right in thinking the discriminant of $L'''' = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{13}) = (4\cdot39)^2$? Doesn't it matter that $3\equiv3(mod\ 4)$ and $13\equiv1(mod\ 4)$? So for my question above,  is the discriminant of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-1}) = -20^2 = 400?$

**Q4**. What about cubic root combination number fields?

From one of the topics on [StackExchange Answer #2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33573/ramification-in-a-tower-of-extensions):

The intermediate fields of $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5},\sqrt{-1})$ are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Is the third intermediate field always the product of the $m_i$? This intuitively makes some sense but I don't fully understand why is it so? My instructor didn't give any explanation for it when I asked her. She asked me to refer the textbook. In the last paragraph of the answer it says ...$p$ has to ramify in both. I don't get it. Why would p have to ramify in both? I think that's a silly question and if I put a bit more thought I might get it but I nevertheless asked if somebody is willingly to answer all these.

Thank you so much in advance for explaining me.

Answer (score 2):

First, to avoid confusion, we must recall that the discriminant of a number field $K$ is the discriminant of any $Z$-basis of its ring $R_K$ of integers. Because of this arithmetic flavor, the computation of disc($K$) in general is not easy, unless we know in advance a description of $R_K$ (which is rarely the case). Coming back to your questions:

**Q1**. For quadratic fields $K, R_K$ is known, hence disc($K$) is also. You can find in any text book on algebraic number theory that, if $K = Q(\sqrt d)$, where $d \in Z$ is square free, a $Z$-basis of $R_K$  is {$1,\frac 12(1+\sqrt d)$} or {$1, \sqrt d$}  according as $d $ is congruent or not to $1 mod 4$. So the disc. is $d$ in the first case, $4d$ in the second. I let you compute  and check the result announced by Wiki. for $d=-15$. The question now is how to compute the disc $Q(\sqrt d, \sqrt d')$, or more generally to compute  the disc. of the composite $MN$ of two number fields $M, N$ of respective degrees $m, n$. A sufficient result is known, see e.g. Marcus' "Number Fields", pp. 33-34: let $\delta$ = gcd (disc($M$), disc ($N$)) and  suppose that the degree of $M.N$ over $Q$ is $mn$; then $R_{MN}$ is contained in $\frac 1\delta R_M .R_N$  . In particular, if $\delta=1$, then $R_{MN}=R_M .R_N$, and you can compute disc $MN$ from those of $M,N$. In the particular case of biquadratic fields, the condition on the degree $mn$ is void. For your biquadratic example or that of Wiki., this should also work (I'm too lazy to check). But beware : you must compute separately the cases $L'$ and $L"$, because these fields are not equal; as for your L''', it is quadratic, not biquadratic.

**Q2**. I cannot recall the definition of a "ramified prime ideal $P$" in an extension of number fields $L/K$, you must look for yourself in any textbook. The extension $L/K$ is said to be "unramified everywhere" if any prime ideal $P$ of $R_K$ is unramified in $L$. There is a link between ramification and the relative (ideal) discriminant $D(L/K)$ of $L/K$ : $P$ ramifies iff it contains  $D(L/K)$. But here, knowing the biquadratic field $L$ and its quadratic subfields, you can proceed directly, happily enough. Take a prime ideal $P$ of $K$ and the prime number $p$ "under it", i.e. $P \cap Z = pZ$. As above, $p$ is ramified in $K$ iff $p$ divides disc($K$). In the Wiki. example, if lucky, you can check that the "candidates" $p$ to ramification are not common divisors of the disc. of $K$ and of another quadratic subfield of $L$  and you are done. In Samuel's booklet "Algebraic Number Theory",you can look at exercise 1, chapter 6, to get an idea of the road map.

**Q3**. Just apply the recipe in **Q1**.

**Q4**. The combination of cubic fields is much more complicated. Even if you can apply the sufficient result above, the ring of integers of a cubic field is awful, even for a "pure cubic" one, i.e. of the form $Q(\sqrt [3] d)$. See e.g. Marcus, p.38.

Pffft... I'm exhausted.